# Readfile and change letters

Tags: python

Am using python and i would like to read a text file and change first character to be the last

```
f = open("words.txt", 'r')
print f.readline()
k = f[1:]+f[0]
print k
f.close()
```

Comment: Why are you only reading one line? You may want to use `file.read`

Comment: The problem is all about changing the first character to be the last character from text file

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change each line in the file, you can use [fileinput.input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input) with `inplace=True` to modify the original file:

```
from fileinput import input

for line in input("foo.txt", inplace=True):
    line = line.rstrip()
    print(line[1:] + line[0])
```

If you want the very first char added to just the last line without reading all the data at once you can write to a [NamedTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) and do a [shutil.move](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) to replace the original file with the updated tempfile

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from shutil import move

with open("foo.txt") as f, NamedTemporaryFile("w", dir=".", delete=False) as out:
    ln = sum(1 for _ in f)
    f.seek(0)
    start = next(f)
    ch = start[0]
    out.write(start[1:])
    for ind, line in enumerate(f, 2):
        if ind == ln:
            out.write("{}\n".format(line.rstrip()+ch))
        else:
            out.write(line)

move(out.name,"foo.txt")
```

So foo.txt:

```
123
456
789
```

Will be replaces with:

```
23
456
7891
```

You could call .read and slice and replace which would be fine for small files:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from shutil import move
with open("foo.txt") as f, NamedTemporaryFile("w", dir=".", delete=False) as out:
    data = f.read().rstrip()
    out.write("{}\n".format(data[1:] + data[0]))

move(out.name,"foo.txt")
```

But  you are keeping two copies of the data in memory so that may not work for very large files.